# Swap number in a text file using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Interchange the numbers which are in the center (applicable for 4 digit numbers, if is less or more than 4 digits return input.)

Comment: expected output for `12345`?

Comment: It only swaps 4 digit numbers. If it is less than 4 or more than 4, it returns the input @komatiraju032

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
def swap(n):
    if len(n) == 4:
        return n[0]+n[2]+n[1]+n[3]
    return n

with open('Data.txt') as fp:
    data = [line.strip() for line in fp if line.strip()]
    res = list(map(swap, data))
    print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
['1324', '245', '4758']
```